# Eliminar scrollbars en Chrome cuando no hay overflow

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

En Google Chrome cada vez que tengo un overflow sea del tipo que sea, me muestra las scrollbars y no encuentro la forma de que sólo aparezcan cuando realmente hay overflow en el tipo `overflow: scroll`, porque me muestra también las scrollbars cuando en otros tipos de overflow.

Comment: Si pones `overflow:hidden` también te lo muestra? Pon algún ejemplo para poder verlo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Con el valor `auto` debería mostrarte únicamente el scroll cuando es necesario:

```css
div{
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</div>

<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
```

Comment: Gracias. Sólo me pasa en Windows, en Mac no. Lo que no sé es si lo pongo en auto, ¿por defecto coge `overflow: scroll`?

Comment: @JetLagFox El valor por defecto de `overflow` es `visible`

Comment: Efectivamente, como dice @blonfu, el valor por defecto es `visible` que indica que el contenido se muestra aunque exceda el espacio del contenedor. El valor `scroll` indica que se mostrarán barras de desplazamiento sean o no necesarias. El valor `auto` indica que sea el navegador el que decida que hacer con el contenido que no quepa en el contenedor. Por lo general, en los navegadores de escritorio, se muestran barras de scroll únicamente en caso de ser necesarias (aunque no hay garantía de que el funcionamiento sea éste)

Comment: ¡Gracias por la respuesta! Lo dejaré en auto pues.